# JDBC classpath issue

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I don't like to post a question when so many suggestions pop up when I type the question title in but looking through them all and seeing no solution is somewhat distressing. I've been following a tutorial for java->postgres connections and I am constantly getting slaughtered by

```
"Could not find or load main class Seb"
```

error messages.

I've tried using

```
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%:<path to work directory>;<path to jdbc jar>
```

compiling like so:-

```
javac -cp .:jdbc.jar Seb.java
```

and executing like so:-

```
java -cp .:jdbc.jar Seb
```

and can't see through the light -_-

The thing is, following the tutorial down to the letter (and watching the demonstration video) doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm simply using notepad and cmd.exe on Windows 8 for development as it's only a learning opportunity, not a big project - but I'm baffled as to why I can't get the thing to run!

JDBC postgres files are in the same directory as .java file.

Code is available if needed as is any other information I can provide.

Thanks in advance for any help,

-Tim!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a semi-colon classpath separator for Windows

```
java -cp .;jdbc.jar Seb
          ^
```

Read: [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: Also, is Seb not in a package? If it is, it needs to be run with the.name.of.the.package.Seb

Comment: Thanks Reimeus. The tutorial uses a colon and changing it to a semi-colon instantly resolved the issue :/ very very much appreciated! (Also, will accept answer in 11 minutes when SO lets me)